# shell script to disassemble object files?

Tags: shell, scripting

I have never in my life made a shell script (although I have had to find and delete multiple troll ones my friends put on my school account when i am not looking).

I have some .o files under the working directory. I want a shell script that, by being given a simple (no path) .o file name, finds the matching file under the current directory and then runs the shell command

```
 arm-none-eabi-objdump -D <found file>
```

So if I give it example.o, it will find dir1/dir2/example.o and then run

```
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D dir1/dir2/example.o
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shell script isn't especially needed for this, but I will attempt to cover all approaches.  This assumes that the shell of choice is bash, but this may work for other shells as well.  First, you need to consider whether you may have multiple object files with the same name, and what you may want to do if you do.  If you want to dump only the first match, then this should work for you:

```
find ./ -name example.o -exec arm-none-eabi-objdump -D '{}' \; -quit
```

If, however, you want to dump all found matches, you can either remove the `-quit` (which will concatenate the output) or put the command in a loop:

```
find ./ -name example.o |
while read file; do
    arm-none-eabi-objdump -D "$file" | less
done
```

If you wish to save yourself the typing (or reverse search) and put this in a shell script, all you need to do is put the same text in a file, add at the beginning of the file `#!/bin/bash` on its own line, and then make the file executable via `chmod a+rx my-script.sh`.  Then you can run the script by typing `./my-script.sh example.o` (assuming you are in the same directory as the script).  Note that unless you put the script somewhere in your `PATH` environment variable, then you do need the `./` before the file name.

Comment: How would I go about giving the name as a command line argument to the shell script?

Comment: I have updated my answer to give a little more detail on that, as well as the potential issue you may run into with executable permissions.